# datetimepicker in datagridview not allowing to enter same date twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, datagridview, datetimepicker

hello I am using c# and datagridview is already in place in my application where the columns are bind to another class
what I have to do is
embed a datetimepicker in my datagridview so that I can select date from it which is then bind to the variable and converted into the correct format before inserting into the database.
I am only working on UI other developer has done the backend code.
my code so far is
in main class

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
```

then on mouse click event

```
private void cliOrderStackGrid_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cliOrderStackGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "orderDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn" && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                //DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
                cliOrderStackGrid.Controls.Add(dtp);
                dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                Rectangle rectangle = 
                cliOrderStackGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex, true);
                dtp.Size = new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                dtp.Location = new Point(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y);
                dtp.TextChanged += new EventHandler(datetimepicker_textchanged);
                dtp.Visible = true;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error in adding date in column" + ex.Message);
        }
      
       
    }

   private void datetimepicker_textchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cliOrderStackGrid.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text;
    }
```

My issue is if I am selecting the same date twice then the date does not add to the datagridview neither binds but if I am selecting new date everytime its working perfectly
Sorry if the question is not correct to ask I am a new programmer and have limited knowledge.
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know whether this is related to your issue but why would you do this: `cliOrderStackGrid.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text.ToString();`? For one thing, the `Text` property of a control is type `string` so the fact that you're calling `ToString` on it suggests that you're not really thinking about data types properly. Secondly, why would you commit the cardinal sin of storing dates as text? There's simply no justification for it. The `Value` property of the `DateTimePicker` is type `DateTime` and that is what you should use and store. The grid can format it for you.

Comment: As for the issue, I wonder whether it's because you're handling the `TextChanged` event and the `Text` won't change if you use the same date so there's no event so there's no value stored in the cell. You're not setting an initial value in the control based on the cell either. You would do much better to handle the `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events. Push the value from the cell to control in the former and from the control to the cell in the latter. One reason to do that is that it allows the user to cancel the edit without affecting the cell.

Comment: if I am doing it like this 
 cliOrderStackGrid.CurrentCell.Value = dtp;
It is giving me error 
system.windows.form datetimepicker cannot be converted to 
type system.datetime

Comment: And why would you do it like that? Maybe read the words I actually wrote and do what I actually told you to do. We shouldn't have to explain something to you twice when the first explanation is right in front of you to read as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after trying for so many days I get to the root cause of it..
I was not able to enter the same date one after the other but if the date was different I was able to easily enter it so basically if the text is not changed then the date was unable to be added
That was because I was using `text_changed` event handler instead I have added

```
cliOrderStackGrid.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text;
```

to the `cellClick` event and the problem is solved!